# Automatically adjust the width of an element

Tags: html, css

Recently I was assigned the task of building a web component using HTML and 
CSS. **This component is part of form** and is composed of:

- an element on the left, which can be a label, span or something similar
- an item on the right that is usually going to be a button
- and between the above elements will be located a central element which has the behavior of self-adjusting to the remaining space between the other elements.

I want to achieve this:

[image: I want to achieve this]

I couldn't find a solution that met all the above criteria and finally we ended up using flex to assemble the component.

I'm looking to build this component using only HTML and CSS, **without using (and this is very important) JavaScript, or any library or JavaScript framework, or flex (FLEXBOX).**

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
.middle {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2aff00;
}
.middle > * {
    /*¿¿??*/
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
}

/*clearfix*/
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">

        <div class="left">
            <span>left elem.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <button>right elem.</button>
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="description" style="margin-top: 2em">
      
      
      
        <div><span style="background: red">left elem.:</span> A label or span element that is use as a label. <b>Has fixed width</b></div>
        <div><span style="background: #2aff00">middle elem.:</span> An input like text, select, etc. <b>Has a variable width!.</b> It most resize in the remaining space between the left and rigth elements</div>
        <div><span style="background: blue">right elem.:</span> A button or selectable input. <b>Has fixed width</b></div>
    </div>
```

**The right element might or might not be present**, and this is the behavior of my component, so I can't always know his width. This is why I need that the middle container to be dynamic.

And no overflows can be used in the middle container as this feature can hide part of the element.

**UPDATE:**

Finally solved: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/aee/pen/RMXBEQ)

Comment: just curious – why "no flex"? do you need to support some ancient browser?

Comment: What helb said and if no flexbox, does that also mean no CSS Grid? Can you include which browsers/versions you are supporting?

Comment: What do you mean by flex? Flexbox? That *is* CSS, so your requirements are contradictory.

Comment: @helb please dont try to go outside the problem i just described. The "why" i dont want to use flex is out of discussion. As i wrote in the question, i ended up using flex to solve my problem. What I'm asking is, can i use other tools to achieve this?. Tools present in the market for a long run.

Comment: @aee Please don't be rude; if you're going to impose arbitrary restrictions and not give any reasoning then we won't be able to help *you* with the problem *you came to us for help* on.

Comment: @TylerH sorry. It wasnt my intention to be rude. I just want to say that flex is out of scope of the problem.

Comment: @aee Ah, okay. I was just wondering why are you trying to invent some weird convoluted solution to a problem almost perfectly solved by flexbox. Well, I'm out then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use floats on the label and button elements, floating them left and right. This will take both of them out of normal flow and push them as far left and right of their container.

Floating the elements also forces block level elements that come after them in the mark up to push up in there container, so in the mark up anything that you want to come up and fill the space between the floated elements should come after.

Floating elements also causes their container element's height to collapse if there is no content that is larger in height than the element that was floated. We can get passed this by using a clearfix solutions. One clearfix solution is to create a new block formatting context since one features of them is that the contain floats

Another feature of a block formatting context is that they respect floats and will shrink their width when the come up next to them instead of ignoring the. So can create a another block formatting context that will respect the floats of the label and the button and shrink to fit the space in between. There are many ways to create block formatting context. In my demo below I have opted for setting the overflow to auto.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

label {
  float: left;
}

button {
  float: right;
}

.input-container {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <label for="">I am label</label>
  <button>Button</button>
  
  <div class="input-container">
      <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is some information on block formatting contexts](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/understanding-css-layout-block-formatting-context/)

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer!. This cannot resolve the problem as the overflow feature hide part of the middle container

Comment: It does not hide part of the container, it goes far as it can left or right as block formatting will always respect floated elements. Setting overflow to auto still allows the element to grow. You can just add some padding to the middle element to separate the input from the edge of it's container, I've updated the code above to show this. inspect the code using your browser tools to see what I mean about the respecting the floats.

Comment: Your answer seems to be very close to what im looking for but everytime i tried your code (in my browser or codepen) some part of the input goes underneet the button element. Also, adds a scroll var to the bottom of the input. I will keep trying to make it work a little more

Comment: If you could provide me with screenshots of the problems that my solution causes that would help as this solution works fine on my machine.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kTOrNS
I also addeded in codepen: https://codepen.io/aee/pen/Zxgmad

Comment: You can hide the scrollbars by using overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; I've updated the code snippet above to show this.

Comment: Close but no, that only hides the scrollbar. It still hides part of the input.
I was twitching your code and found a solution to my problem. It was missing a "box-sizing: border-box" property to the input element.
If you remove those overflow-X to your answer and add the border-box to the input i'll give your answer as correct. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah! Yes as the border of the input would add extra width to the input's size. I've updated my answer. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```css
.area-class {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.area-class-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.single-wrapper {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
.single-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="area-class">
    <div class="area-class-inner">
        <div class="single-wrapper">
            your content
        </div>
        <div class="single-wrapper">
            your content
        </div>
        <div class="single-wrapper">
            your content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```